# Password strength in Entity Framework 4.1

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc-3

I need to create a regular expression for password property of Entity Frame work 4.1 model class.

Requirement is:

password must be 6-18 characters and contain at least one letter and one number. Special characters such as @, %, &, # are permitted.

```
    [Required]
    [StringLength(18, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)).+$", ErrorMessage = "Password doesn't meet the requirements")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

How can I modify it to allow special characters. Does this regular expression force to have one letter and one character, If no, how can I change the regular expression. someone suggested me to add this logic in membership/ provider tag in web.config. How can I do this in web.config.

```
<membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
             connectionStringName="CreditRegistryDB" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true"
             requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordStrengthRegularExpression =""
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Comment: There is no password strength in EF. That is logic completely handled by your application and EF has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

The following regular expression should meet your requirements:

```
^.*(?=.{6,18})(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*[@%&#]{0,}).*$
```

This has the following requirements:

- Between **6 and 18 characters** in length
- Must contain at least **one letter** and **one number**
- May contain one or more special character from your list **@, %, & and #**

The **curly braces** after your special characters represent the following:

- {1} Exactly 1 occurrence;
- {6,} At least 6 occurrences;
- {2,6} 2 to 6 occurrences.
- {0,} At least 0 occurrences; <-- in your case

You can test this regular expression using [REGex TESTER](http://www.regextester.com/) to make sure it meets your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can I make these special characters. I don't want these special characters required but If someone enters them then it should validate.

Comment: I have updated my answer showing the same RegEx but with optional special characters. {0,} means it required a minimum of 0 of the characters inside the brackets []. If you required 2 special characters but no more than 4, you could change this to (?=.*[@%&#]{2,4})